# Is there any postman like client for protobuffer

Tags: protocol-buffers

I want to develop a protocol-buffer type RESTful API that replaces JSON with protocol-buffer.

For example, a Spring Boot implement:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("account")
public class AccountController {

    @RequestMapping(
        path = "ListAccount",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = {"application/x-protobuf", "application/x-protobuf;charset=UTF-8"},
        produces = {"application/x-protobuf", "application/x-protobuf;charset=UTF-8"})
    public ListAccountResponse listAccount(ListAccountRequest request) {
        // do something
        ListAccountResponse response = ListAccountResponse.newBuilder().build();
        return response;
    }
}
```

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "account.proto.api";

package account.api;

import "common/pagination.proto";
import "common/valid.proto";
import "account/data/account.proto";

message ListAccountRequest {
    common.Pagination page = 1 [(valid.validate) = true];
}

message ListAccountResponse {
    repeated account.data.Account accounts = 1;
    common.Pagination page = 2;
}
```

It seems that no a GUI client like postman for testing protocol-buffer API, which make me writing a tester in java. I will appreciate it if someone can tell me the answer.

Comment: Let's create an open source one :D

Comment: I have found [protoman](https://github.com/spluxx/Protoman) for testing the API, but it doesn't work expected.

Answer (score 1):

I personally find Kreya https://kreya.app/ to be the best tool for interacting with gRPC API

BTW Postman now supports gRPC too.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: Nope. Just another GRPC api dev

Answer (score 0):

You can use BloomRpc.First of all you should import your proto files and after that change format of request according to your rpc service.

Comment: thanks, but BloomRPC is for rpc service not https+proto.

Comment: You can take place Rest Auto Controller mechanism in front of rpc services and call them via Swagger

Answer (score 0):

you can use protoman A Postman-like API client for protobuf-based messages.
https://github.com/spluxx/Protoman